# VBA's .removeDuplicates does not appear to work... Why?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a column vector, let's say

1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1

and I need to programmatically remove duplicates.  So after the removal of duplicates the output should be just:

1 2

However, VBA's .removeDuplicates method fails, triggering Error 1004 (application defined error).
My setup as follows:
I have one workbook that contains the actual data.  Second workbook contains the vba code that operates on the first workbook.

Observation #1:

When I execute the .removeDuplicates method from within the data-containing workbook and therefore data containing worksheet, the code works like a charm.

```
sub test  
 ActiveSheet.Range("$a$2:$a$20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
end sub
```

Observation #2:

However the moment that I try to run the very same code from a another workbook (with slight modification to address the fact the code is external to the first workbook), the .removeDuplicates fails:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    'get a handle to data containing workbook and sheet
    Set wb = Workbooks(1) 'change wb index as needed
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("s2") ' change sheet name  as needed
    sh.Range("$a$2:$a$20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Anyone had to deal with this before?  Can I not use .removeDuplicates from another workbook?  I look at the MSDN's API and there is no mention on limitations...

Comment: Have you test by Workbooks(2) not Workbooks(1).

Comment: Code successfully works for me, even when run from a different workbook.  Do you have any `On Error` statements that you aren't showing us?  (And I guess I should ask the obvious question ... is "s2" a `Worksheet` or a `Chart` or something else?  E.g. it will give a 1004 error if it is a macro sheet.)

Comment: Ignore the last part of my previous comment - if it was a macro sheet rather than a worksheet, you would get the 1004 error even when the code was run from the same workbook.

Comment: s2 is just a name of a worksheet.  so just  to make sure I understand you correctly, you are able to run the .removeDuplicates method out of workbook #2 and apply that method successfully within workbook #1?

Comment: Yes.  The only way I could get it to fail is if "s2" wasn't a worksheet, e.g. if it was actually a macro sheet (which **looks** very similar to a worksheet).  I didn't test it, but I assume it would also fail if the worksheet was protected, or if some of the cells were merged, or something similar.  But none of those reasons would allow it to work when you ran the macro within the actual workbook - i.e. just running the macro from a different workbook is not a cause for the error.

Comment: The only reason I can see this failing is the Workbooks(index) you're using. If you opened the workbook containing the macro before the one you want to manipulate, the one containing the macro would have index 1.

Comment: I suspect your object references are not referencing what you think they may be.  Instead of using an index into the workbook collection, refer to the workbooks by name (or at least add some code to ensure that you are referencing the correct location).

Comment: Apart from repeating what has already been mentioned (make sure you are looking at the correct workbook), this highlights the importance of properly qualifying your workbook and/or your worksheets. Setting workbook to **`Workbook(1)`** is heading for a pitfall. It might work for a bit but is likely to fail at some point. You can use the workbook collection to set workbook object to the correct one which is a lot more reliable

Comment: guys, thanks for suggestions.   I think I am referencing all the right sheets and workbooks.  The easiest way to check that is to issue command sheet.name or workbook.name.  If object is pointing elsewhere or is null, then there will be wrong name or no name at all.. I checked all of that, all pointers check out.

Comment: When you say the remove duplicates fails - in what way. Your code should remove duplicates from a3:a10 (since you define a2 as the header)

Comment: @HarassedDad, what I meant by 'fail' is that no expected operation is performed.  In other words, application error 1004 is being triggered

Comment: @zac, thanks for a great comment.  yes I agree with you 100%  and we can talk more about how to write excel perfect code, but this does not address the original error I am facing.

Comment: @YowE3K, I am a little confused...  what is the difference between 'macro sheet' and a 'worksheet'?

Comment: @Slaqr, I do not think so...  all workbooks are contained in the same collection object under one excel instance.  So whether something is opened before or after is completely irrelevant.  We can query the right workbook by the name instead of index if you like.  In the sample code, the index is hard-coded to '1' for simpcity and there is a caption 'Change is needed' that i originally put as I do know what index it will be on your machine:  While on mine it is '1',  it could be 1020, if you have over 1000 workbooks open.

Comment: A macro sheet is a hangover from the times before VBA. You can accidentally create one by pressing Ctrl-F11. (Apart from the fact that entering formulas in one just leaves the formula showing instead of being evaluated, you can tell that it's a macro sheet by the default name of "Macro1".) A macro sheet is not a work sheet, therefore it is not a part of the `Worksheets` collection, and none of the usual worksheet operations will work on it.  But it is part of the `Sheets` collection - another good reason why people should use Worksheets("s2")` instead of `Sheets("s2")`.

Comment: But if you had a macro sheet, your code wouldn't work correctly even when the macro was run from the active workbook, so I don't think that can be an explanation for your issue.

Comment: @YowE3K, thanks for a clarification and explanation.  I checked and I do not have any macro sheets.  Just the regular sheets whose behavior is driven by VBA.

Comment: "So whether something is opened before or after is completely irrelevant."  No! When you open a workbook it is appended to the workbooks collection and its index number is the next sequential value. So the first workbook you open in a session is workbooks(1) and the next one you open is workbooks(2) , If you change the order you open them in, you change their index numbers.  I suspect that the problem is that Workbooks(1) is not the workbook you think it is.

Comment: @HarassedDad, and that is why we check indices and change them as needed  Remember,  the code above is 'proof-of-concept', not the prod code.  I am not here to write self-sustained prod code for that captures all the cases.  The objective is to diagnose an entirely diff error.  you need to assume that everything else works, if not, then follow instructions in the sample code and change indices accordingly to make things work.  Let's not divert onto other important but unrelated topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove duplicate behavior is bizarre, sometimes it works but sometimes not, basically it won't work while a cell is blank in selected range. to avoid remove duplicate run time error u could use following Procedure

```
Call remove_duplicate(ThisWorkbook.Name, "Mysheets", 14, 400)
```

Above calling initiates following SUB and works same as remove remove duplicate
Where

ThisWorkbook.Name is workbook name, for your case it is "1". 
Mysheets is sheet name so your case it will be "s2". 
14 = Column Number, for your case it is 1. 
400 = Last Row number, for your case it is 20.

```
Sub remove_duplicate(ByVal WorkBookName As String, ByVal worksht As String, ByVal col_Number As Integer, ByVal LastRow As Integer)
'WorkBook must be open withwise won't work
'col_Number = the column u want to test duplicate value

Dim i As Long
Dim CalcMode, ViewMode As Variant

Workbooks(WorkBookName).Worksheets(worksht).Activate

If LastRow <= 1 Then  'if Rows on column is empty or only contains header then exit the sub
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

ColChr = Split(Cells(1, col_Number).Address, "$")(1)
With ActiveSheet
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    Range("A1").Select
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        CheckVal = Range(ColChr & i).Value
        CountVal = Application.CountIf(Range(ColChr & ":" & ColChr), CheckVal)
        If CountVal > 1 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Calculation = CalcMode
   .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```